# How to generate all possible splitting of a list?

Tags: ocaml

Given a list: `[1; 2; 3]`, how can I generate all possible splits:

```
[
  [ [1; 2; 3] ]; 
  [ [1]; [2; 3] ]; 
  [ [1]; [2]; [3] ]; 
  [ [1; 2]; [3] ]
]
```

I have no real attempt yet, I don't know how to start

EDIT : attempt

I tried to do it step by step but it's kinda messy
and I couldn't do mergeFirst, without mergeFirst it gives : `[[[1]; [2; 3]]; [[1]; [2]; [3]]]`

Am I on the right path ? I don't think my code will work if the list contains more than 3 elements too ...

```
let split = function
| []    -> []
| x::y -> [[x::y]] @ [[[x]] @ [[List.hd y]]]
 
(* let mergeFirst a = function
... *)
  
let addtoseperatelist a list = 
  List.map (fun t -> [[a]] @ t) (list)

let rec generateAllSplit =  function 
| [] -> []
| [x;y] -> split (x::y::[])
| x::y -> addtoseperatelist x (generateAllSplit y) @ (mergeFirst x (generateAllSplit y))
 
let myList = [[1;2;3]]
let _ = generateAllSplit myList
```

Comment: Within each list of possible ways to split it up, the same number cannot appear more than once? E.g. "splitting" `[1; 2; 3; 4]` cannot yield `[[1; 2]; [2; 3]; [3; 4]]` but `[[1; 2]; [3; 4]]` would be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

Until you get farther with your analysis, this isn't actually an OCaml question. It's more a question about breaking down a problem recursively.

One good way to solve problems that feel recursive is to imagine that you already had the solution. If you had your split function already, it would return the following for the tail of your list (`[2; 3]`):

```
[ [[2; 3]];  [[2]; [3]] ]
```

Is there a way to process this smaller result into your desired final result? Yes. There are two things you can do with `[1]`: you can merge it with the first element of the returned lists, or you can add it as a separate list. That gives you the four values of the desired result. You should be able to prove to yourself that his always gives the right answer. (Or maybe it doesn't, you'll have to check.)

If your given list has fewer than 2 elements, the result is obvious. You can probably combine this with the above recursive processing to get the answer.

Comment: I haved edited my post to add my attempt but it doesn't feel right

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The merge first is still missing, which you have to do with pattern matching because the empty list is a special case. In my code that is `(function [] -> [[x]] | z::zs -> (x::z)::zs) ys`

The one element list is also a special case for split because it only has one result. If you would solve that recursively you would get `[[x]; []]` and `[[x] @ []]` == `[[x]]`.

Instead of adding to the recursive results and merging to the recursive results and then appending the two resulting lists I decided to use a `fold_left` and construct the adding and merging of each sub list in parallel. Then you can `::` the results instead of append:

```
let myList = [1;2;3]  

let rec split = function
| [] -> [[[]]]
| [x] -> [[[x]]]
| (x : int)::xs ->
    List.fold_left
      (fun (acc : int list list list) (ys : int list list) ->
        ([x] :: ys) (* add to separate list *)
        :: (function [] -> [[x]] | z::zs -> (x::z)::zs) ys (* merge first *)
        :: acc
      )
      []  
      (split xs)  

let res = split myList;;

val myList : int list = [1; 2; 3]
val split : int list -> int list list list = <fun>
val res : int list list list =
  [[[1]; [2; 3]]; [[1; 2; 3]]; [[1]; [2]; [3]]; [[1; 2]; [3]]]
```